# web server as a non root user

Tags: webserver, lamp

I searched on google about this but couldnt find much. I need to setup a server on a non root user account ,so that people can access it and store information on this. Can you tell me how can I do this?

I thought of installing LAMP as a non root user . will this do ?

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply choose a port greater than 1023 and you can be any user. Only root can open a port between 1 and 1023, and the "normal" port for web access is 80.

Comment: if someone wants to save files on this server they can use the port which I set . And only apache server is enough or should we install LAMP?

Comment: LAMP means Linux, Apache, MySql, and PHP(or Perl).... install whichever pieces your web environment will need.